# Replace internal PCB antenna with external antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna

I want to replace these internal antennas with an eternal cable antenna - see pictures.

I'm not an analogue engineer...am I going to run into trouble removing one of these and soldering a cable onto the PCB?

Thank you for your wisdom!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will probably run into trouble for sure.

Comment: How about soldering a pcb mount smc connector?

Comment: Without knowing the details of the existing antenna, it is difficult to be precise, but you are highly likely to run into impedance mismatch (and therefore reflections) issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific design, you have 2 antennas. 
As replacement, you have 3 options, in order of reliability:

1. Find whatever SMT connector fits the 2 empty footprints and a suitable adapter to your antenna and adjust the resistors accordingly.
2. Solder a piece of wire, ~1/2 Wavelength to the relevant pad.
3. Cut the antenna connector and solder the coax directly to the pads.

Don't expect miracles. This is an unreliable connection at best, and might destroy your board at worst.

Comment: Thanks! I can try these solutions. I actually have a lot of these PCBs so I'm not to worried about trashing a few.